# Runnung a motor continuously

Tags: tolerance

I have a blower motor which runs on 12v with 25min running 5min rest rating. I want to run it at 5v-1amp (significantly lower speed) for at-least 14hour continuously. Will that hurt burn the motor? The reason I think it may work is because I am running almost at the third of the rated voltage.

Comment: Will it start or even run properly at 5V?

Comment: It will certainly stall more easily at 5V. 14 hours is ~28 times longer than 25 minutes. And 5V is nowhere near 28 times less. So even not knowing anything about motors, intuition should tell you something will go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the limitation is power/heat buildup...

The power dissipated in the motor winding is a square function... if you decrease the voltage by 50% (and therefore the current) you have decreased the power by a factor of 4... down to 25% of its original value. Any motor rated to run for 25min "ON" time, and at 80% duty cycle, will surely have no problem running continuously at 5 volts... if indeed it will run at all.

Just understand that you don't have a say over how much current the motor will try to draw.  If it required 25 Amps at 12V, that's the equivalent of 2.083 Ohms in the windings. At 5 Volts and 2.08 Ohms, it's still going to require around 2.4 Amps.  (although the load of the fan/blower will be quite a less at the lower voltage & speed, offsetting some of the Current)

As long as the motor will run at 5 Volts, and it doesn't try to overload your 5V power source, it should be fine.

Comment: A hand on the motor will also give a good idea of how its coping.

Comment: Yes, it runs approximately at 5/7GPM at 4cm water at 4.6V which is what I need. Coming from physics background power/heat buildup is what I assumed is the limitation - but was not sure if that is it.  BTW the rating of the blower is 12V 8A peak, I do not have a power supply to check the running amps at 12v.